# Python - Remove(convert to white) non black pixels of an image

Tags: python, png, ocr

I have a png file that I want to remove all the non-black pixels(convert non-black pixels to white). 
How could I easily do that in Python? Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library

Comment: Related: [How to select all non black pixels in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735231/how-to-select-all-non-black-pixels-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

# Separate RGB arrays
im = Image.open(file(filename, 'rb'))
R, G, B = im.convert('RGB').split()
r = R.load()
g = G.load()
b = B.load()
w, h = im.size

# Convert non-black pixels to white
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        if(r[i, j] != 0 or g[i, j] != 0 or b[i, j] != 0):
            r[i, j] = 255 # Just change R channel

# Merge just the R channel as all channels
im = Image.merge('RGB', (R, R, R))
im.save("black_and_white.png")
```

Comment: Why not just convert to L, threshhold it so everything >0 becomes 1, then convert back? That's a lot simpler, and it'll probably be an order of magnitude or so faster (since it does the big slow loop in C instead of in Python).

Comment: Could you please tell us, what will be the change if want to change black color to transparent or white?

Answer (score 2):

I did this on my mac using home-brew, and I dunno which operating system you use so I can't give you more specific instructions, but these are the general steps you need to take if you haven't done them already:

1) install libjpeg (if you are gonna be dealing with a .jpeg file, pil does not come with this)

2) install pil (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ OR through homebrew or macports etc. if you are using a mac)

3) link pil with python if needed

4) use this code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("/pathToImage") # get image
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for i in range(img.size[0]): # for every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        if pixels[i,j] != (0,0,0): # if not black:
            pixels[i,j] = (255, 255, 255) # change to white

img.show()
```

Feel free to ask leave comments if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: You are converting all black pixels to white.  He needs all non-black pixels converted to white.

Comment: Oh oops I must have misread I'll fix it asap