# How to select all non-black pixels in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to get a list of an image's pixels that are different from a specific color using NumPy.

For example, while processig the following image:

[image]

I've managed to get a list of all black pixels using:

```
np.where(np.all(mask == [0,0,0], axis=-1))
```

But when I try to do:

```
np.where(np.all(mask != [0,0,0], axis=-1))
```

I get a pretty strange result:

[image]

It looks like NumPy has returned only the indices were R, G, and B are non-0

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read mask
mask = cv2.imread("path/to/img")
excluded_color = [0,0,0]

# Try to get indices of pixel with different colors
indices_list = np.where(np.all(mask != excluded_color, axis=-1))

# For some reason, the list doesn't contain all different colors
print("excluded indices are", indices_list)

# Visualization
mask[indices_list] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow(mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) instead of [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) for the second case of selecting all but black pixels:

```
np.any(image != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
```

Or simply get a complement of black pixels by inverting a boolean array by [`~`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html):

```
black_pixels_mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
non_black_pixels_mask = ~black_pixels_mask
```

---

**Working example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = plt.imread('example.png')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
image_copy = image.copy()

black_pixels_mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)

non_black_pixels_mask = np.any(image != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)  
# or non_black_pixels_mask = ~black_pixels_mask

image_copy[black_pixels_mask] = [255, 255, 255]
image_copy[non_black_pixels_mask] = [0, 0, 0]

plt.imshow(image_copy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

In case if someone is using matplotlib to plot the results and gets completely black image or warnings, see this post: [Converting all non-black pixels into one colour doesn't produce expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214017/converting-all-non-black-pixels-into-one-colour-doesnt-produce-expected-output)

Comment: Still it's unclear for me why it should be `np.any` instead of `np.all`. I will think more about it and try to provide explanation. But in any case, I would prefer using `~`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think i realize now why np.any is necessary. What happened when I used np.all is that the array only containd colors with R!=0 AND B!=0 AND G!=0. Which meant that the color [255,0,0] resulted in False. by using np.any the condition became R!=0 OR B!=0 OR G!=0

Answer (score 1):

Necessity: Need matrix with this shape = (any,any,3)

**Solution:**

```
COLOR = (255,0,0)
indices = np.where(np.all(mask == COLOR, axis=-1))
indexes = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
for i in indexes:
    print(i)
```

**Solution 2:**

get interval of specific color, for example RED:

```
COLOR1 = [250,0,0]
COLOR2 = [260,0,0] # doesnt matter its over limit

indices1 = np.where(np.all(mask >= COLOR1, axis=-1))
indexes1 = zip(indices[0], indices[1])

indices2 = np.where(np.all(mask <= COLOR2, axis=-1))
indexes2 = zip(indices[0], indices[1])

# You now want indexes that are in both indexes1 and indexes2
```

**Solution 3 - PROVED to be WORKING**

If previous doesnt work, then there is one solution that works 100%

Transform from RGB channel to HSV. Make 2D mask from 3D image. 2D mask will contain Hue value. Comparing Hues is easier than RGB as Hue is 1 value while RGB is vector with 3 values. After you have 2D matrix with Hue values, do like above:

```
HUE1 = 0.5
HUE2 = 0.7 

indices1 = np.where(HUEmask >= HUE1)
indexes1 = zip(indices[0], indices[1])

indices2 = np.where(HUEmask <= HUE2)
indexes2 = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
```

You can dothe same for Saturation and Value.

Answer (score 0):

For the special case of selecting non-BLACK pixels, it is faster to convert the image to grayscale before looking for nonzero pixels:

```
non_black_indices = np.nonzero(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
```

Then to change all the black pixels to white, for example:

```
img[non_black_indices] = [255,255,255]
```

Again, this only works for selecting non-[0,0,0] pixels, but if you are crunching through thousands of images, the speed boost over the more general approaches becomes significant.